# getting exception "org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize" after removing bidirectional mapping from entity in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, bidirectional-relation

I am getting below exception while I removing ManyToOne mapping from client model below are the entities I

Application Entity looks like:

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = "Application.findAll", query = "SELECT a FROM Application a")
public class Application implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "APPLICATION_ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "OLO_ID_SEQUENCE")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "APPLICATION_ID_GENERATOR")
    private long id;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to User
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_USER")
    private User user;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to ClientData
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "application", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<ClientData> clientData;
    .
    .
    .
```

Client entity looks like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CLIENT_DATA")
@NamedQuery(name = "ClientData.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM ClientData c")
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class ClientData implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "CLIENT_DATA_ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "OLO_ID_SEQUENCE")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "CLIENT_DATA_ID_GENERATOR")
    private long id;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "BIRTH_DATE")
    private Date birthDate;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "CREATION_DATE")
    private Date creationDate;

    @Column(name = "GENDER")
    private String gender;

    @Column(name = "NAME1")
    private String name1;


    // bi-directional many-to-one association to Application
    /*@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_APPLICATION")
    @JsonIgnore*/
    @Column(name="ID_APPLICATION")  
    private Application application;
```

I have commented the many to one mapping from client data and trying to get application. but getting below error.

```
 Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize] with root cause
    java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2638)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:3113)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:854)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:349)
        at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:328)
        at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:318)
        at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:237)
        at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:306)
        at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.fromBytes(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:155)
        at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:130)
        at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:44)
        at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarbinaryTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarbinaryTypeDes
```

Comment: In which operation you are facing this exception? deserializing? can you share your service?

Comment: I am facing it in service layer where I am getting details to process further.                
if (pApplication.getClientData() != null
     && !pApplication.getClientData().isEmpty()) {
    lGetAppResponse.setClientData(pApplication.getClientData());
   }

Comment: please share your service

Comment: Issue has been resolved by annotating service as @Transactional. Now I am able to get mapped data on service.